# Widget & Static Block vs. Template File

Tags: template, static-block, widgets

When is it more appropriate to create a `.phtml` file and place it via `local.xml`, and when is it more appropriate to create a widget and place it in a static block via the backend?

For example, I once had my custom main navigation as a widget/block on the backend, but moved it into a `.phtml` file and included it with my `local.xml` so that I could more easily make changes, use version tracking, etc.

My main concern is the impact it could have on performance, since my main navigation includes a list of dozens of Magento categories.

So whats 'best practice'? Does it matter? Does it impact performance?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think there is a right answer for this.
The path you choose depends on your needs.
I usually avoid using widgets. Specially when working with "not so technical" clients.
The widget system in Magento is not that easy to use or to explain to someone else.
I usually put everything in phtml files so the chance of something getting screwed up is smaller. Or if something gets screwed up, I know it's my fault and I know where to look.

From time to time I like to create widgets with a minimum configuration needed, but I do this only when the client wants to use the widgets in the homepage or other static pages.
I rarely tell my clients about the full widget system of magento, that allows you to place widget instances on different sections of each page. I rather spend 30 minutes adding something on the left column, than spending 2 hours looking for how to remove something placed wrong on the left column.

But in almost all the cases I avoid using `local.xml`. That looks to me like it's a bit dirty. I think it's better to put your custom widgets or blocks or phtml files inside a custom module. The advantages are:

- portability (you can easily isolate and re use the module in another project)
- you can easily disable you functionality if needed
- the chances of something going wrong in an upgrade are lower and if something goes wrong...refer to the point above.

Performance can be affected even if you use a widget or a phtml file. I don't think the difference is significant. Maybe it's a little slower with the widget approach because the widgets have to be parsed and interpreted, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Its helpful to get an authoritative view on the topic. Thanks Marius

Comment: I don't know about "authoritative". I'm not an "authority" on this. It's just my opinion and what I found during the years.

Comment: Well, I guess what I meant is, I trust your opinions :P

Answer (score 0):

You have to create first .phtml file.
Link that file to any static block using indentifier.

getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('your identifier')->toHtml(); ?>

it's quite easy for further change at any time.